# How to get maximal/minimal significant value of multiple fields where some fields can be 'null'

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, firebird

I have a query with multiple columns of same type. They originate from a detail table that is `left join`-ed with its master table multiple times.

Per result record, I need the maximum and minimum of significant values of these columns. That is `null` values should not be taken into account.

There are [`MAX()`](http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-max) and [`MIN()`](http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-min) aggregate functions in Firebird. Unfortunately, they accept only one single field as parameter.

Further, there are [`maxvalue()`](http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-maxvalue) and [`minvalue()`](http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-minvalue) functions, which accept multiple parameters. Unfortunately, these functions return `null` when at least one value is `null`. I just want to ignore `null`-values and return `null` only when all values are `null`.

---

The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b13d0b/4) is just an example of a query that returns multiple columns which can be `null`. As SQL Fiddle does not support Firebird I used MySQL 5.6 for **demonstration purposes only**. But finally, I need a solution for Firebird.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Master
    (`ID` int)
;

INSERT INTO Master
    (`ID`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
;


CREATE TABLE Detail
    (`MREF` int,
     `MYVALUE` int)
;

INSERT INTO Detail
    (`MREF`, `MYVALUE`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select m.ID, d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE
  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b13d0b/4/0)**:

```
| ID | MYVALUE | MYVALUE | MYVALUE |
|----|---------|---------|---------|
|  1 |       1 |  (null) |  (null) |
|  2 |  (null) |       2 |  (null) |
|  3 |  (null) |  (null) |       3 |
```

---

Desired output would for the very simple above example would be:

```
| ID | MYVALUE | MYVALUE | MYVALUE | MAX | MIN |
|----|---------|---------|---------|-----|-----|
|  1 |       1 |  (null) |  (null) |   1 |   1 |
|  2 |  (null) |       2 |  (null) |   2 |   2 |
|  3 |  (null) |  (null) |       3 |   3 |   3 |
```

Comment: There is only three value columns? I dont see a way beside multiple nested `case` but isnt easy to mantain if columns change

Comment: Currently, there can be up to five columns. But this might change in future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the other answers, I concluded that there have to be encapsulated terms. Since those produce complicated queries, I had a look at **UDFs** (user-defined functions).

I found `F_MAXDATE()` and `F_MINDATE()` in [FreeAdhocUDF's date functions](http://freeadhocudf.org/documentation_english/dok_eng_datum.html#vergleichen). Unfortunately, they behave similar to Firebird's internal functions `maxvalue()` and `minvalue()` as they return `null`, if any input param is `null`.

As there seemed to be no other UDFs fitting my needs, I wrote them on my own.
At first, it seemed to be that they return fuzzy values. If `null` is passed to them, they returned `17-11-1898 00:00:00` in some cases. That is, because Firebird does not pass `null` to UDFs by default but passes `null`-equivalent values instead. In case of `TIMESTAMP` this is `17-11-1898 00:00:00`.

To enable `null`-passing to UDFs one has to [extend the UDFs params declaration with `NULL`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-notes-udf-null.html).

Thus, it worked when I changed my UDFs' declarations to something like this:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION MAX_TIMESTAMP
    TIMESTAMP NULL,
    TIMESTAMP NULL
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
ENTRY_POINT 'MAX_TIMESTAMP' MODULE_NAME 'HKSCommonUDF';
```

With my newly written UDFs my example query looks like this (for `TIMESTAMP` values):

```
select m.ID, d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE,
       max_timestamp(max_timestamp(d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE), d3.MYVALUE),
       min_timestamp(min_timestamp(d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE), d3.MYVALUE)
  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Firebird

```
select m.ID
       ,nullif(maxvalue(coalesce(d1.MYVALUE,-999999999),coalesce(d2.MYVALUE,-999999999),coalesce(d3.MYVALUE,-999999999)),-999999999) as max_val
       ,nullif(minvalue(coalesce(d1.MYVALUE, 999999999),coalesce(d2.MYVALUE, 999999999),coalesce(d3.MYVALUE, 999999999)), 999999999) as min_val
  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```

#### MySQL

```
select m.ID
       ,nullif(greatest(coalesce(d1.MYVALUE,-999999999),coalesce(d2.MYVALUE,-999999999),coalesce(d3.MYVALUE,-999999999)),-999999999) as max_val
       ,nullif(least   (coalesce(d1.MYVALUE, 999999999),coalesce(d2.MYVALUE, 999999999),coalesce(d3.MYVALUE, 999999999)), 999999999) as min_val
  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```

Comment: This is for `MAX()`, but same idea for `MIN()` just using `99999`

Answer (score 0):

Mysql equivalent for `maxvalue()` and `minvalue()` are `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` but only accept two parameters, so is a litle more complicated. But same logic

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/JNMT44412)**

```
select m.ID, d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE,
       NULLIF(
               GREATEST( 
                        GREATEST( COALESCE(d1.MYVALUE,-99999),
                                  COALESCE(d2.MYVALUE,-99999)),
                        COALESCE(d3.MYVALUE,-99999)
                       ),
               -99999
             ) as max_value,
       NULLIF(
               LEAST( 
                        LEAST( COALESCE(d1.MYVALUE,99999),
                               COALESCE(d2.MYVALUE,99999)),
                        COALESCE(d3.MYVALUE,99999)
                       ),
               99999
             ) as min_value             


  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**: Only `CASE` version, no need `-99999` dummy code, but doesnt get preaty with 5 columns

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/FSZ58270)**

```
select m.ID, d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE,
       CASE WHEN d1.MYVALUE IS NULL AND d2.MYVALUE IS NULL AND d3.MYVALUE IS NULL  THEN NULL
            WHEN d1.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN d2.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d3.MYVALUE
                                              WHEN d3.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d2.MYVALUE
                                              ELSE GREATEST(d2.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE)
                                         END
            WHEN d2.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN d1.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d3.MYVALUE
                                              WHEN d3.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d1.MYVALUE
                                              ELSE GREATEST(d1.MYVALUE, d3.MYVALUE)
                                         END
            WHEN d3.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN d1.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d2.MYVALUE
                                              WHEN d2.MYVALUE IS NULL THEN d1.MYVALUE
                                              ELSE GREATEST(d1.MYVALUE, d2.MYVALUE)
                                         END                                         
            ELSE GREATEST(GREATEST(d1.MYVALUE,d2.MYVALUE), d3.MYVALUE)
       END as t,


  from Master m
  left join Detail d1
    on d1.MREF = m.ID and d1.MYVALUE = 1
  left join Detail d2
    on d2.MREF = m.ID and d2.MYVALUE = 2
  left join Detail d3
    on d3.MREF = m.ID and d3.MYVALUE = 3
```